# printing from firefox spits extra blank page at the END

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing

I have a web page that prints correctly on Chrome and IE, but has the followign problem on Firefox:

The actual content is shown page 1. And extra blank page prints page 2.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%;` applied to a BODY tag seems to push any stray whitespace off the end of the first page and onto a second.  I got bitten by this, and once removed, it prints just fine.  You could try adding `overflow:visible;` as well.